# How to show rate this app message on dashboard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is it possible to use appirater, iRate or other method to show "rate this app" message when user go back to dashboard. I tried to use appirater in applicationdidenterbackground. But the message didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

When your application is going to background the popup won't be visible for a user - it will be shown within your app. You can show it when user goes back to your app using:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: Is there any other way to make this popup appear on dashboard. Different than appirater or iRate.

Comment: No I don't think so - if user wants to close your app - why would you bug them with that ? :)